# Dropdown Menu Not Dropping Down (CSS/HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a drop down menu that drops down under the navigation bar (Snooze Land specifically, for testing purposes), but for some reason it adds itself to the right. I'm still learning (codeacademy) and would appreciate help.

Below is HTML. I took out a few unrelated parts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#meetArtist">Slothie's Nests</a></li>
            <li id="snooze"><a href="#assignments" >Snooze Land</a></li>
            <ul id="test">
                <li><a href="#">Services-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services-2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#snoozelings">Mini Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Social Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("snooze").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'inline-block';
    console.log('attempt');
        document.getElementById("snooze").addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
})
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is CSS. Only thing I left out are font imports

```
/* Universal Styles */

html {
    scroll-padding-top: 8em;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Karla, serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url(resources/PurpleSquares.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 290px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 6rem;
}

.body-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100rem;
    background-color: #eff7fa;
}

.art-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.art {
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.arttwo {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.artthree {
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

.artfour {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

img {
    width: 25rem;
    
}

/* Nav Styles */

nav {
    margin-top: .5rem;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    border-top: gray 2px solid;
    border-bottom: gray 2px solid;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

nav a {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: rem;
}

nav a:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding-top: .8rem;
    padding-bottom: .8rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.line {
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#test {
    display: none;
}
```

I've tried changing the type of the display. Making it block messes up the bar even more. I tried different web results for making a list, but none seem to work because I'm still learning to code and my stuff could be optimized better.

Comment: [This is a good tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) on drop-down menus.

Comment: I've looked at that page but my menu is list items and I can't get it work work with how my menu works

Comment: So change your menu to be more like the tutorial. Using `<ul>` and `<li>` for menus is overkill. A `<nav>` containing a list of `<a>` links is all you need. But for dropdowns, you need an overall wrapper element, containing both an element to click on and a wrapper containing your second-level menu items. The overall wrapper is needed in order for the hover or mouseover/mouseout to work correctly.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you Brett :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#meetArtist">Slothie's Nests</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"
        id="snooze"><a href="#assignments">Snooze Land</a>
      <ul id="test"
          class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Services-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#snoozelings">Mini Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Social Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("snooze").addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
      document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
    });

    document.getElementById("snooze").addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
      document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Universal Styles */

html {
  scroll-padding-top: 8em;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Karla, serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url(resources/PurpleSquares.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 290px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6rem;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100rem;
  background-color: #eff7fa;
}

.art-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.art {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.arttwo {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.artthree {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

.artfour {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

img {
  width: 25rem;

}

/* Nav Styles */

nav {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  border-top: gray 2px solid;
  border-bottom: gray 2px solid;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav a {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: rem;
}

nav a:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  padding-top: .8rem;
  padding-bottom: .8rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.line {
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

#test {
  display: none;
}

/* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

/* Style the submenu (hidden by default) */
.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Show the submenu when the parent is hovered */
.dropdown:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```